# SQL Case statement where searched expression contains case statements for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to perform a CASE to CASE subtraction inside another case.

Here is a simplified part of the query ( I am only including the case part for brevity)

```
-- Sum up if the shift is contracted
CASE 
   WHEN s.IsAbsence = 0 AND s.IsAnnualLeave = 0 AND s.IsOvertime = 0 
   THEN SUM(s.ShiftHours) 
   ELSE 0 
   END AS [Shift Hours],
-- Sum if the shift is paid over and above contract hours
CASE 
   WHEN s.IsOvertime = 1 OR s.IsAnnualLeave = 1 
   THEN SUM(s.ShiftHours) 
   ELSE 0 
   END AS [Paid Hours],
-- SUM if the colleague is absent
CASE 
   WHEN s.IsAbsence = 1 
   THEN SUM(s.ShiftHours) 
   ELSE 0 
   END  AS [Unpaid Hours],
```

This is the part that I need help with. Net Hours cannot be less than zero due to other calculations so if the first case minus the second case is less than zero it should be zero.

```
CASE
   WHEN
   CASE 
      WHEN s.IsOvertime = 1 OR s.IsAnnualLeave = 1 
      THEN SUM(s.ShiftHours) 
      ELSE 0 
      END 
   - -- This is a minus
   CASE 
      WHEN s.IsAbsence = 1 
      THEN SUM(s.ShiftHours) 
      ELSE 0 
      END
   < 0
THEN 0 
ELSE (Perform the minus above)
END
```

Put simply IF ((a - b) < 0) return 0 else return (a - b)

Comment: Use `GREATEST(a - b, 0)`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I suggest introducing a subquery or common table expression (CTE) so you can build up your logic in multiple steps without having to go cross-eyed reading nested expressions.

Comment: You would likely find this easier with a CTE so that you can materialise your expressions first. Also `CASE` is an expression in SQL, *not* a statement.

Comment: @TheImpaler: `GREATEST` is only available in Azure (Synapse), not any on-prem version of SQL Server, so its use is limited. Hopefully it'll get added to SQL Server 2022.

Comment: @JeroenMostert According to the docs it's available at least in SQL Server 2016 through 2019. Maybe I'm reading wrong: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: @TheImpaler: [it isn't supported](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce3386bdd40ec4b7a89e63ca8247647d). Look at the top of the docs: "Applies to: Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only)". It would have to say "Applies to: SQL Server (all supported versions)", as it does with [`CHOOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql). (No, I don't know why the docs choose this confusing way to present things -- it might be a bug.)

Comment: Aside: It looks like you want to have the `case` expressions _inside_ the `sum` aggregations, e.g. `Sum( case when s.IsAbscence = 1 then s.ShiftHours else 0 end ) as Unpaid_Hours`. The term of art is _conditional aggregation_, i.e. when the organism is absent then their hours contribute to the unpaid hours summation.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I stand corrected. I failed to see that top bar. "It just in front of my eyes".

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's just a column alias

Comment: @HABO Spot on the issue, also solves the other problem I was facing which was being forced to use Group BY on all columns thanks to aggregate function so you solved 2 problems in 1. If you make your comment an answer I will mark as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is one of *conditional aggregation*, in this case summing hours into different categories depending on some status derived from other columns. That is easily accomplished by moving the conditional logic *inside* the aggregation:

```
-- Sum of all regular shift hours.
Sum( case
  when s.IsAbsence = 0 and s.IsAnnualLeave = 0 and s.IsOvertime = 0 then s.ShiftHours else 0 end
  ) as [Shift Hours],
-- Sum of hours paid over and above contract hours.
Sum( case when s.IsOvertime = 1 or s.IsAnnualLeave = 1 then s.ShiftHours else 0 end ) as [Paid Hours],
-- Sum of hours when the colleague is absent.
Sum( case when s.IsAbsence = 1 then s.ShiftHours else 0 end ) as [Unpaid Hours]
```

For each row processed the conditions will be evaluated and the hours credited or ignored by summing either `s.ShiftHours` or `0` as appropriate.